# Conversation exits after redirect user to google assistant phone app from Google Home

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to redirect user to his phone at some specific point after a little conversation with Google Home. User must type a product code on his google assistant app to trigger new intent.

The redirect is okay, user sees a notification, click on it and go to a conversation with my custom assistant which tells him to type the code. To do so : I made a dialogflow intent with `actions_intent_NEW_SURFACE` and my fulfillment api makes a response with a custom message which will be shown in phone app.

But when the user tries to type the answer (the product code indeed), conversation ends without any call to my fulfillment api (only with a general message : "sorry, don't understand", like a google assistant fallback). I don't know what is the problem. I suspect that my assistant loses the context or google assistant kill my own assistant.

Have you ever faced this issue ?

Thanks !

MC